# How to bind card data from one component to another component card in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, axios

i have two components one is Displaying cards which is responsible to show the data into a card which comes from backend(DisplayNotes.vue) and another one is updating the existing data card by opening popup(updateNotes.vue), if the user clicks on any card it opens one popup which is responsible for editing data but in my case if the user clicks on any card it should opens the popup-card(UpdateNotes.vue) along with the existing data,Here my question is How to get data from the card into a popup card [[Here i am clicking 4th card ,when ever i click on the forth card the content should bind to the pop-up card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5Rk2.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5Rk2.png),please help me to get the data into a popup card

`DisplayNotes.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="carddisplay-section" >
    <div  v-for="note in notes" :key="note.id"  id="blur" class="container note">
        <div @click="toggle(note.id)" class="card-content">
            <h5>{{note.title}}</h5>
            <p>{{note.body}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="import-icons">
            <icons class="imported-icons note-icons" />
            <button v-if="flag" class="card-button" type="button" @click="handlesubmit();Togglebtn();">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="popup">
        <UpdateNotes :cardId="clickedCard"/>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../service/User'
import icons from './icons'
import UpdateNotes from './UpdateNotes.vue'
export default {
    name: 'DisplayNotes',
    components: {
        icons,UpdateNotes
    },
    data() {
        return {
            flag: true,
            notes: [{
                id: 1,
                title: 'Fundoo',
                body: 'unlimited notes..'
            }, ],
           clickedCard:'',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        Togglebtn() {
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
        async handlesubmit() {
            service.userDisplayNotes().then(response => {
                this.notes.push(...response.data);
            })
        },
        toggle(id){
            var blur=document.getElementById('blur');
            blur.classList.toggle('active');
             this.clickedCard = id;

            var popup=document.getElementById('popup');
            popup.classList.toggle('active');

        },
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "@/styles/DisplayNotes.scss";
</style>
```

`UpdateNotes.vue`[popup]

```
<template>

<div v-if="flag==false" class="update">
    <form class="update-note" @submit.prevent autocomplete="off">
        <input name="title" v-model="title" placeholder="Title" />
        <textarea name="content" v-model="body" style="resize: none" placeholder="Take a note..." rows="3"></textarea>
        <div class="btm-icons">
            <icons />
            <button id="btn-section" type="submit" @click="handlesubmit();flip();">Close</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

</template>

<script>
import icons from './icons.vue'
import service from '../service/User'
export default {
    components: {
        icons
    },
    props: ['cardId'],
    data() {
        return {
            title: '',
            body: '',
            flag: false,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        flip() {
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
        async handlesubmit() {
            let userData = {
                id: this.cardId,
                title: this.title,
                body: this.body
            }
            service.userUpdateNotes(userData).then(response => {
                alert("Note updated  successfully");
                return response;
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "@/styles/UpdateNotes.scss";
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing the id of the card in the popup, similarly pass the data of the currently clicked card in the popup.

`UpdateNotes.vue`

```
<template>

<div v-if="flag==false" class="update">
    <form class="update-note" @submit.prevent autocomplete="off">
        <input name="title" v-model="title" placeholder="Title" />
        <textarea name="content" v-model="body" style="resize: none" placeholder="Take a note..." rows="3"></textarea>
        <div class="btm-icons">
            <icons />
            <button id="btn-section" type="submit" @click="handlesubmit();flip();">Close</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

</template>

<script>
import icons from './icons.vue'
import service from '../service/User'
export default {
    components: {
        icons
    },
    props: ['cardId', 'cardContent'],
    data() {
        return {
            title: '',
            body: '',
            flag: false,
        }
    },
    created () {
        this.title = this.cardContent.title;
        this.body = this.cardContent.body;
    },
    methods: {
        flip() {
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
        async handlesubmit() {
            let userData = {
                id: this.cardId,
                title: this.title,
                body: this.body
            }
            service.userUpdateNotes(userData).then(response => {
                alert("Note updated  successfully");
                return response;
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "@/styles/UpdateNotes.scss";
</style>
```

`DisplayNotes.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="carddisplay-section" >
    <div  v-for="note in notes" :key="note.id"  id="blur" class="container note">
        <div @click="toggle(note.id)" class="card-content">
            <h5>{{note.title}}</h5>
            <p>{{note.body}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="import-icons">
            <icons class="imported-icons note-icons" />
            <button v-if="flag" class="card-button" type="button" @click="handlesubmit();Togglebtn();">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="popup">
        <UpdateNotes :cardId="clickedCard" :cardContent="cardContent"/>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../service/User'
import icons from './icons'
import UpdateNotes from './UpdateNotes.vue'
export default {
    name: 'DisplayNotes',
    components: {
        icons,UpdateNotes
    },
    data() {
        return {
            flag: true,
            notes: [{
                id: 1,
                title: 'Fundoo',
                body: 'unlimited notes..'
            }, ],
           clickedCard: '',
           cardContent: {}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        Togglebtn() {
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
        async handlesubmit() {
            service.userDisplayNotes().then(response => {
                this.notes.push(...response.data);
            })
        },
        toggle(id){
            var blur=document.getElementById('blur');
            blur.classList.toggle('active');
            this.clickedCard = id;

            this.cardContent = this.notes.filter((note) => note.id === id);

            var popup=document.getElementById('popup');
            popup.classList.toggle('active');

        },
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "@/styles/DisplayNotes.scss";
</style>
```

Comment: Hello @Yash Maheshwari, The data is not bind in the form inplace of  placeholder="Title" and "Take  a Note" which is present in the UpdateNotes.vue

Comment: if i click on any card it opens one popup(updateNotes.vue), in my case i need the content which contains the card that data will be present inside the popup card,@Yash Maheshwari

Comment: Can you check what you are getting in the `created()` hook by console.log(this.cardContent)?

Comment: Hello @Yash Maheshwari, i am getting the data of a clicked card on console, i am wrighting console.log() in DisplayNotes.vue inside the toggle(id)

Comment: Can you change `autocomplete` to on in the form tag?

Comment: i changed it but nothing happens

Comment: like this i am getting on console                                                                         body: "two binds"
created_at: "2021-05-29T07:45:26.000000Z"
id: 22
title: "Afterupdate"
user_id: 2

Comment: In the created hook check a console like `this.cardContent.title`?

Comment: i think we have to pass created() hook content into form

Comment: Use `this.title = this.cardContent[0].title` and `this.body = this.cardContent[0].body` in the created hook.

Comment: Also check whether you are getting `cardContent` data in the UpdateNotes.vue

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at VueComponent.created (UpdateNotes.vue?dc57:31)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854)
    at callHook (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4219)
    at VueComponent.Vue._init (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5008)
at new VueComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5154)at createComponentInstanceForVnode (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3283)
    at init (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3114)
    at createComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5978)
    at createElm (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5925)
    at createChildren (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6053)

Comment: i am getting this error on console and not getting any cardcontent data inside the updateNotes.vue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233985/discussion-between-yash-maheshwari-and-sravani).

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined at VueComponent.created` that's because `cardContent` is never set a value